# First character of a bullet list automatically aligned at right with no option to change it

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, list, bullets

I've been working 100 hours and more in the same text document. Suddenly, today, I tried to copy-paste a block of text from the web into a bullet list and realized there was a problem I never saw before on Word 2016. Now, the problem is in my whole document and I cannot do any type of list.

[image]

In the two screenshots that follow below, I enabled the option "Show All (CTRL+*)" to see what was the problem more precisely. When I hover my mouse on the arrow, there is no information label and no way to remove it.

[image]

[image]

Is this a bug? Is there a way to remove this option? Or to modify directly the settings about how bullet lists are made and interact in this particular text file?

Comment: You have a left tab stop at the right hand end of the ruler. Drag it left to where it should be or drag it off the ruler to delete it.

Comment: See [Using the ruler in Word - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-ruler-in-word-775014ca-7bb9-4b75-ba19-4478c4a836d1) for more information.

Comment: You might in any event recover the prior document using Word Options, Save, Auto Recover location. If that works, make a good back up and then try the formatting suggestion above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance, I finally found a work-around solution. The feature named [Clear all text formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clear-all-text-formatting-c094c4da-7f09-4cea-9a8d-c166949c9c80?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) has solved my problem. I selected the text I wanted to put in a list, I cleared the text formatting with this button and I can now create a normal bullet list.

This is only a partial solution, since I must do it with for each block of text I want to create a bullet list.

It's still not clear what caused the problem initially.